# Method Delegation and Adding a field

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to implement method delegation and also add a field to track dirty fields in a class by delegating all setters.  My class instantiation looks like this:

```
        T t = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass (typeClass)
            .defineField ("dirtyFields", List.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .method(ElementMatchers.isSetter())
        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(SetterInterceptor.class))
            .make ()
            .load (SetterInterceptor.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
            .getLoaded ()
            .newInstance();

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String> ();
    t.getClass().getField("dirtyFields").set(t, l);
    l.add("foobar");

    return t;
```

and my interceptor looks like this:

```
  @RuntimeType
  public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> superMethod, @Origin Method method, @Super(proxyType = TargetType.class) Object delegate) throws Exception {
    System.out.println ("---- Intercept");
    markDirty (delegate, Character.toLowerCase (method.getName ().charAt(3)) + method.getName().substring(4));
    return superMethod.call();
  }
```

However, I'm unable to get the "Object" that the setter is being called on, and delegate does not seem to reference that object.  I'm wondering if there is something I need to do, or something I can inject, to provide this capability.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you should avoid using the `@Super` proxy on the target class which is rather expensive. Rather have an `CanBeDirty` interface that all of your instances implement and base the proxy on this interface.

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question by injecting @This into the interceptor:

```
  public static Object intercept(@This Object thiz, @SuperCall Callable<?> superMethod, @Origin Method method, @Super(proxyType = TargetType.class) Object delegate) throws Exception {
```